# Prioritise, categorise and share To Do list

Tags: gratis, web-apps, todo

I'm looking for a way of creating a To Do list.

There are 4 of us in my team and each person will have a list of tasks. I want to set a priority and category to each task and have each assigned to one of us.

I'd like to be able to see all tasks in a single list and also be able to filter them by team member, priority and category.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to add notes in an individual task.

I could do it in Excel but wondered if there is any software that does it out of the box.

Also, I work for the health service and paid software won't be an option unfortunately.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this points you in good direction: Kanban is a visual workflow management method that optimizes processes by displaying tasks on a board. This helps teams track work progress efficiently, typically using columns like "Todo," "In Progress," "Done," and "QA". But you could also do this with a single column layout where you only have a "Todo" column. Online Kanban tools offer features such as assignments, labels, notes, and comments. So finding a Kanban tool with your requirements should not be to hard. Finding a free HIPAA-Compliant Kanban board might be challenging, but there are open-source options available for self-hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Was also recommended Todoist so will look at both.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/67341)